# Git: add, commit and rebase/squash in same operation

Tags: git, rebase, git-commit

I often find myself on a feature branch, having committed a change. Then, I figure out I have to make a change, so I:

1. Make the change
2. Add all the file changes to the index using `git add -A`
3. Commit the changes using `git commit -m <commit message>`
4. Rebase the changes and squashing the last two commits using `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, and squashing the newest commit, so that I end up with 1 commit

This is a flow I commonly use a lot, but it feels quite cumbersome and manual. Is there a smarter way of doing this, or is it more common to just create shell functions or aliases for this kind of task? I am talking about steps 2 through 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to modify a commit which you just made to the HEAD of a feature branch would be to *amend* that commit via:

```
git commit --amend 'your commit message here'
```

Git commit amend works by creating a *new* commit, functionally identical to the old one, plus your new changes, and then replacing the old HEAD commit with the new one.

Note that this rewrites history, so it would not be suitable for branches which you have already pushed and which may have been pulled by other people already.  But it is not worse in this regard than your current rebase approach.

As an alternative to your heavy duty rebase approach, there is a much simpler way to squash the two top commits of a branch.  You can do a soft reset, followed by a commit:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit -m 'made a small change to latest commit'
```

Git reset soft works by moving the HEAD pointer back two commits (in this case), while leaving both the working directory and stage as they were.  This has the effect of essentially staging the work done in your first commit, plus the second patch commit, on top of the commit immediately prior to your first commit.  Then, when you commit this work, you will have effectively squashed everything down to just a single commit.

But most of the time I find myself using commit amend more than reset soft to handle this situation.

Comment: Haven't tried it but maybe `--amend` and `-all` work together, so you can omit the `git add` if it's just changes to existing files?

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge I've never heard of that, but doing `git add -A` once doesn't bother me so much :-)

Comment: Using `--amend` is usually the right answer. I find it helpful to note that it it works, in essence, by shoving the current commit aside and substituting the new amended commit in its place. As you note, this "rewrites history" (pretends as though your "amended" commit never happened: *don't look at that one, look at this new one instead!*). But it's an extremely common case: *Work, work, work; test. Yay, bug fixed! Commit! Run full test suite. Oops, forgot special case! Re-fix, amend commit, re-run full test suite...*